# Difficulty with a locator(using java for selenium)

Tags: java, selenium

Complete newbie here...started trying to learn selenium with java this month.
Having troubles locating one button, because it seems to lack name id, link and its class is weird looking. Can someone help me write a locator for it? Its an accept cookies button.

```
<button type="button" class="_908LZ _1pO2V m29-z _4R7G3 _2JFg2" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Приемане на всички бисквитки" data-qa="privacy-settings-action-info">OK</button>
```

Comment: Just from the looks, `data-qa` seems to be the "contract" between developers and testers to identify this element. As such, developers should try hard to keep this stable. If my assumption is correct, use this attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either of the `xpath` option to identify the element.

```
By.xpath("//button[text()='OK']")
```

OR

```
By.xpath("//button[@data-qa='privacy-settings-action-info']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the answer by @KunduK,

you can use the following xpath to add more filter -

`//button[@data-qa='privacy-settings-action-info'][text()='OK']`